# How would i import a Resource file into a DGV

Tags: c#, visual-studio

how would i add data from a resources textfile to a DGV
the data in the txt file is in the form

Mark 1
where Mark is the user
and 1 is the id so,

Mark 1

John 2

Bill 3

etc

```
AG.Rows.Add(Resources.AGboard.Split(' '));
```

This is what i have right now but i get this error

```
Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table
```

There are 2 colouns in DGV, Name and ID

Comment: Did you read the error message? What do you think it is telling you? Hint: What do you think the `Split` function is doing to this entire file?

Comment: yea thats the problem, im trying to add each item on a new row, and there are 2 coloumns like there should be

Comment: Create an intermediate variable that is the result of the Split. Debug and look at the value and then consider if it makes sense to add that result to a grid row. You need to split on lines, and then split each line on your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to import the resource file to the datagridview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Resources;
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("NameCol", "Name");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("IDCol", "ID");
            string filename = @"Your resource filepath";
            ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(filename);
            foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Resource file:

[image]

Result:

[image]